# reason for program termination before method

Tags: java

Trying to learn why my program terminates prematurely. Runs the gallons to liters conversion method ok but stops there. Does not run the "root" method (purpose of which is to compute square roots for number 1 to 100). I believe this is more an issue of formatting than semantics. Thank you for help.

```
package gallons.to.liters;  

public class converter {                    
public static void main(String args[]) {    
    double gallons;                          
    double liters;          

    gallons = 10;
    liters = gallons * 3.7854;

    System.out.println("The number of liters in " + gallons + " gallons is " + 
            liters);
    System.out.println();

}


public static void root(String args[]) {
    double counter;
    double square;

    square = 0;
    counter = 0;

    for(square = 0; square <= 100; square++); 
        square = Math.sqrt(square);
        counter++;
        System.out.println("The square root of " + counter + " is " +  
                    square);



}       
}
```

Comment: `root` is not supposed to be invoked unless you explicitly do it, e.g. by a line with `root(args);` in `main`. The JVM invokes your `main` only.

Answer (score 1):

You never **call** the `root` method. Add this to the main:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {    
    double gallons;                          
    double liters;          

    gallons = 10;
    liters = gallons * 3.7854;

    System.out.println("The number of liters in " + gallons + " gallons is " + 
            liters);
    System.out.println();

    root(args); // ADD to call the method.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JVM call only `public static void main(String args[])` as entry point of java program.

Actually you never call `root` method inside the `main` method. Call this method to execute statements of `root` method.

Call like this.

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
   ........
   root();
}
```

I find that there is no usage of parameter you pass in `root` method. So remove it.

```
for(square = 0; square <= 100; square++);
```

**Remove semi colon at the end of for loop.**

```
public static void root() {
    double counter = 0;
    for(counter= 0; counter <= 100; counter++) {
        System.out.println("The square root of " + counter + " is " +  Math.sqrt(counter));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a call to the

```
root(args)
```

and there were some problems with your method that i have resolved please find modified version below

```
 public static void root( String args[] )
    {
        double counter;
        double square;

        square = 0;
        counter = 0;

        for ( counter = 0; counter <= 100; counter++ )
        {
            square = Math.sqrt( counter );
            System.out.println( "The square root of " + counter + " is " + square );
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

add line `root(args);` which will call your method.

Whatever there is main method will be invoked till the end of main method. 
Java doesn't run .java file like human reads from start to end. It invokes only those line which are present in the main method. Main method containing lines can invoke other methods which are static or non static according to the programming rule. Best way to understand all these concept is to learn OOP. Purchase two "**Head First core java**" book, one for you and one for your friend and have discussion.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        double gallons;
        double liters;

        gallons = 10;
        liters = gallons * 3.7854;

        System.out.println("The number of liters in " + gallons + " gallons is " + liters);
        System.out.println();
        root(args);  //call this method here as per your expection of the output

    }
```